# float function is reversing a string number when converting to number in Python 3x?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttkbootstrap, ttkcombobox

I've cut this down to the basic functionality I'm looking to fix, as I have more than one combobox, but I'm having an issue when I select the last item in a tuple from a tkinter combobox and convert it to a float.  Somehow it's reversing the number?

I have a similar prototype which works fine, but something in this code is causing this issue?

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import SUNKEN
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *

def handle_selection(event):
    print("In the handle_selection method!")

    selected_index = ti_combobox.current()
    print("selected_index is: ")
    print(selected_index)
    selected_tuple =  ti_combobox.get()
    print("selected_tuple is: ")
    print(selected_tuple)
    selected_float = float(selected_tuple[-1]) # Here the float conversion reverses the number???
    print("selected_float is: ")
    print(selected_float)

window = ttk.Window(themename = 'superhero')
window.title('Basic Tool')
window.geometry('650x350')

main_frame = ttk.Frame(window, relief=SUNKEN, borderwidth=1)
main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

base_finding_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(main_frame, text='BASE', relief=SUNKEN, borderwidth=1)
base_finding_frame.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="news", padx=10, pady=15)

base_label_ti = ttk.Label(base_finding_frame, text='(TI)', font=('Helvetica', 10))
base_label_ti.grid(row=0, column=0)

string_var = ttk.StringVar()
ti_values = [("Crit", "C", "1.0"), ("High", "H", "0.8"), ("Medium", "M", "0.3"), ("Low", "L", "0.2"),  ("None", "N", "0.0"), ("Default", "D", "0.5"),  ("Unknown", "UK", "0.4"),  ("Not Applicable", "NA", "1.0")]
ti_combobox = ttk.Combobox(base_finding_frame, bootstyle='primary', values=ti_values, state = 'readonly', textvariable= string_var)
ti_combobox.grid(row=1, column=0)

ti_combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", handle_selection)

# Run the GUI 
window.mainloop()
```

Here is the output:
In the handle_selection method!
selected_index is: 
0
selected_tuple is: 
Crit C 1.0
selected_float is: 
0.0  **(This removed the digit one and replaced it with zero, which I wasn't expecting!)**
In the handle_selection method!
selected_index is: 
1
selected_tuple is:
High H 0.8
selected_float is:
8.0
In the handle_selection method!
selected_index is: 
3
selected_tuple is:
Low L 0.2
selected_float is:
2.0

Any ideas to what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that  `ti_combobox.get()` is retrieving your values as a single string, not as the tuples you pass when you create the widget.

So, the call to float is actually picking the last *character* you see on the displayed value, and that is resulting in the behavior you printed out.

Just split the string retrieved on the white spaces, before calling float, in order to get the whole number. Replace the line `selected_float = float(selected_tuple[-1])`  with

`selected_float = float(selected_tuple.split()[-1])`

and it should work.

Comment: You are absolutely correct and thanks for the explanation!  Your first sentence was the issue, but I didn't see it.  I don't want to tell you how much time I've spent on this one already.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here. As the combobox values are supposed to be only string., tkinter takes each tuple as a full length of text. So, when you call `selected_float = float(selected_tuple[-1])` It gives the float value of the last character of the complete string. I've modified the code as follows and now it is working as you preferred.

```
def handle_selection(event):
    print("In the handle_selection method!")

    selected_index = ti_combobox.current()
    print("selected_index is: ")
    print(selected_index)
    selected_tuple =  ti_combobox.get()
    print("selected_tuple is: ")
    print(selected_tuple)
    
    selected_list = selected_tuple.split(' ')
    selected_float = float(selected_list[-1]) # Here the float conversion reverses the number???
    print("selected_float is: ")
    print(selected_float)
```